# Forcing Eclipse to surround string with double quotes on export

Tags: eclipse, export-to-csv

Have a current data set that has a column named vendor and it is identified as string.

When Eclipse export the results, it is not surrounding this field in double quotes as it sees only numbers.  This leads to Excel dropping the leading zeros.

Is there a way to make sure all string fields get surrounded by double quotes?

[image: HTML Output from Eclipse Report]

[image: Column Output definition in the dataset]

[image: Field not quoted as text in csv export]

Comment: Which export is this?

Comment: This is once the report is run (using html view) and the user selects to export data

Comment: What HTML view are you talking about? Can you add screenshots?

Comment: What, exactly, are you doing? I have no idea what report you are running or what export you are using.

Comment: Added screen shots of 1) HTML output of report, 2) Column definition of DataSet and 3) CSV out put showing no quotes on String field.  The issue is that when opened in Excel, since not double quoted, it strips the leading zeros